# ASP.NET MVC - How to display an "ActionResult" view that is returned to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth with a custom login provider to sign users into my site.  I have most of the code working, but am having an issue returning the view and displaying it so users can log into the provider.  Basically, the action is returning an actionresult which is the login page on the specific provider back to the calling javascript.  I expected this, as I need to get the login results back to the javascript.  Basically, what happens is I get some error about allowing access then three null boxes (look in the return of the call) and then nothing.  I need it to goto the provider site and log in.

Data Example: url = https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id , requiresUserName = false, username = test (assume it was entered into the textbox).

Below is the code:

JavaScript:

```
function ProviderSignOn(url, requiresUserName) {
    var username = $("#openUserNameText").val();
    if ((requiresUserName == 'True') && (username == '')) {
        clickedProviderUrl = url;
        $('#openUserNameDiv').show('fast');
    }
    else {
        $('#openUserNameDiv').hide('fast');
        $("#openUserNameText").val('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Account/ProviderSignOn",
            data: "provider=" + url + "&username=" + username,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Error);
                alert(data.Message);
                alert(data.Identifier);
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.Error);
                alert(data.Message);
                alert(data.Identifier);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult ProviderSignOn(string provider, string username)
    {
        string providerUrl = provider.Replace("{username}", username);
        bool error = true;
        string message = String.Empty;
        string identifier = String.Empty;

        var response = _openId.GetResponse();

        if (response == null)
        {
            Identifier id;

            if (Identifier.TryParse(providerUrl, out id))
            {
                try
                {
                    return _openId.CreateRequest(providerUrl).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
                }
                catch (ProtocolException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error = true;
                message = "Invalid";
                identifier = String.Empty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    error = false;
                    message = "Success";
                    identifier = response.ClaimedIdentifier;
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    error = true;
                    message = "Canceled";
                    identifier = String.Empty;
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    error = true;
                    message = "Failed";
                    identifier = String.Empty;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return Json(new { Error = error, Message = message, Identifier = identifier });
    }
```

Comment: I notice you're returning Json in the case of an error. I generally wouldn't suggest this; instead, throw an exception. Unless the Json contains data you are planning on showing the user, you could just throw an exception and then use the jQuery `$.ajax`'s `error` option.

Comment: Also note that it's `error`, not `failure`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes this is just code to get me through atm figuring out how to handle the call.  I'll eventually change it to do actual stuff, just want some debug stuff in there atm.  Thanks for suggestion tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are reaching this line of code:

```
return _openId.CreateRequest(providerUrl).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

but then the JavaScript doesn't know how to deal with the redirect result being returned from the Ajax call.

In this case, I would say you are returning the wrong thing. Instead, you should probably do something like this:

```
return Json(new { RedirectUri = _openId.CreateRequest(providerUrl).RedirectingResponse.Uri });
```

but I don't know what kind of object `RedirectingResponse` is (e.g. does it have any kind of `Uri` property?). Just `providerUrl` won't work, right?

Anyway, then in your JavaScript you could do

```
success: function (data)
{
    if (data.RedirectUri)
    {
        window.location.href = data.RedirectUri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually approaching something similar. I did OutgoingWebResponse x = _openId.CreateRequest(providerUrl).RedirectingResponse; return Json(new { Location = x.Headers["Location"] });

That works to get to the provider, but the return to the Action is 404, have to figure that out.

Comment: Also, RedirectingResponse doesn't have a Uri property.  Lease that I see.

Comment: Hmm so that seems like the right idea. But I don't understand what "the return to the Action is 404" means...

Comment: I figured it out, that part was how the return url was being passed back.  But yes, this was the right idea how to handle it, definatly the right answer!